# How to apply parsing and add new column by checking another column from different table in Hive/Impala

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing, hive, impala

I am working on 2 impala tables like these.

table1:

| full_alert |
| --- |
| xyz_visitArizona_xyz |
| klmthak_visitLondon |
| visit_Istanbul |
| tzylpa_visit_Paris |

table2:

| only_name | segment |
| --- | --- |
| Arizona | 1 |
| London | 2 |
| Istanbul | 2 |
| Paris | 2 |

What I want to do is to check **only_name** column in table2, and if the name appears on the **full_alert** column in table1, then create new column as **destination**. Table1 contains different structures for **full_alert** that's why I couldn't use SUBSTR() (I tried and saw many exceptions)

Is it possible to do this in Hive or Impala?

I tried to do this parsing in Jupyter notebook but data is too big and I got either null table or system error whenever I tried to run the query.

desired_table:

| full_alert | destination |
| --- | --- |
| xyz_visitArizona_xyz | Arizona |
| klmthak_visitLondon | London |
| visit_Istanbul | Istanbul |
| tzylpa_visit_Paris | Paris |

Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: ```[ JOIN ON | WHERE ] LOCATE(table2.only_name, table1.full_alert)```

Comment: There is no variable to join 2 tables yet but how can I assign new column by using WHERE? Can I use LOCATE before joining 2 tables?

Comment: *There is no variable to join 2 tables yet* ?? What variable do you mean? Joining condition is an expression whose result can be interpreted as boolean. Any expression, of any complexity, even subquery. *Can I use LOCATE before joining 2 tables?* You must use it **for** joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table1.full_alert, table2.only_name destination
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON LOCATE(table2.only_name, table1.full_alert)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/LqXXYYKI

---

> I tried both these queries but I got an syntax error. – Merve

Apache Impala implements [LOCATE() function](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__locate).

It is possible that it simply does not accept numeric output as logical value. Try this:

```sql
SELECT table1.full_alert, table2.only_name destination
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON LOCATE(table2.only_name, table1.full_alert) > 0
```

Comment: I tried both these queries but I got an syntax error.

```select a.*, b.only_name
from table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON LOCATE(b.only_name, a.full_alert)```
and

```select a.*, b.only_name
from table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.full_alert LIKE CONCAT('%', b.only_name, '%') ```

Comment: @Merve You do something wrongly. Fiddle added.

Comment: Thank you, it might be MySQL  / Impala difference, I'll check and update when I find the issue.

Comment: @Merve Excess tags may produce non-applicable answers. Do not spam with tags.

Comment: @Merve The answer upated.

Comment: Thank you ! After using   > 0, it worked !